# Add a reference to another document in MongoDB | mongocsharpdriver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

So, I have these two models, the second one should contain a reference to the first one.

**Model 1**

```
public class Model1 {
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Model1Id { get; set; }
    ///etc
}
```

**Model 2**

```
public class Model2 {
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Model2Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId Model1Id { get; set; }
    ///etc
}
```

Now, when I try to save the first one, and then update the reference of the second one, the reference shows in the database as `ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")`

This is what I am doing:

```
ctx.Model1.InsertOne(model1); //after this a real ObjectId is saved to the DB

foreach (var m2 in model2)
{
    m2.Model1Id = model1.Model1Id; //this shows as ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")
}

ctx.Model2.InsertMany(model2);
```

How can I do this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found a way. I am not sure if it is the best way. But, maybe someone else can post a better answer in the future.

It seems that there is no way to save more than one `ObjectId` inside a `BSON`besides the `BsonId` (please someone correct me if this statement is false). So, to create this `One-to-One` or `One-to-Many` relationship with the `mongocsharpdriver`, I changed the `Model2.Model1Id` to be a `string` instead of an `ObjectId`.

So the workflow is as follows:

I called `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()` to create a new `[BsonID]` in one of the models.

I updated the references to the second one by calling. `ModelID.toString()`

Now, if I want to find one of the documents that are referenced in the other document, I just have to get the string and create a query calling `new ObjectId(string)`, and that will give me the referenced object that I am looking for.